# JFrame size is too small

Tags: java, swing, jframe, preferredsize

i have created a JFrame in netbeans. But when i run the program, the Jframe size is too small.
here is my code.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;    

public class Window {

    private static void demo()
    {
        JFrame frame =new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
      public void run()
      {
          demo();
      }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: And the output window looks like this.]

Comment: [Swing JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components) by default accepting only PreferredSize,

Comment: *"frame size is too small"*  Put components in it, then call `pack()`.  The frame will become the smallest size it needs to be, in order to display the components inside it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `frame.setSize(width, height)` in order to set its size or `frame.setBounds(x, y, width, height)` for setting both the location and size.

A better choice would be to call `frame.pack()` after you add some components to its content pane.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way...

Use the `setSize(width, height)` method of **JFrame**.

```
public class Myframe extends JFrame{

  public Myframe(){    
      this.setSize(300,300);    
  }

public static void main(String[] args){

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

          public void run(){          
            Myframe f = new Myframe("Frame");
            f.setVisible(true);     
          }
      }); 
    }    
}
```

Comment: f is the instance of the class Myframe that has extends the JFrame

Comment: No no what is visible ? Which method is this ?

Comment: @GagandeepBali sorry for that, i meant to say `setVisible(true);`. I have corrected it.... Sorry for the trouble....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maximize it you could try

```
 this.setVisible(false);
    this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.setVisible(true);
   this.setResizable(false);
```

Else for some specific size use

```
this.setSize(width,height);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one line line so that you can give your frame a size.The line is

```
frame.setSize(300,300);
```

Here is the full code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;    

public class Window {

private static void demo()
{
    JFrame frame =new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
   javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
  public void run()
  {
      demo();
  }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You must have a public component method like

```
public gestion_name_of_class() {
    initComponents();
}
```