# netbeans jframe too small

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

My netbeans JFrame during runtime is very small. However when I'm creating the frame, I have no issues. 
Please help.
I have tried every solution available on the internet. Nothing seems to work

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] , and explain which size the frame is supposed to have .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JFrame size is too small](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100103/jframe-size-is-too-small)